# prove that this formula defines a measure on $(X,\mathfrak{A})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathfrak{A})$ be a measurable space. I'll write just  X.

Show that if {$\mu_n$} is an increasing sequence of measures on X, i.e $\mu_n(A)\le \mu_{n+1}(A)$ for every $A\in \mathfrak{A}$ , then the formula $
\mu \left( A \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \mu _n \left( A \right)
$ defines a new measure on X.

Well .... I have problems with the countable additivity. Let's consider some measurable disjoint sets {$B_i$} . We have to prove the $A=B$ where $$
\eqalign{
  & A = \mu \left( {\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {B_i } } \right)  \cr 
  & B = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {\mu \left( {B_i } \right)}  \cr} 
$$ 
I have to be careful with working in some cases when some set has infinite measure or maybe the countable union has infinite measure.

Well first of all let's note that.
$$
\eqalign{
  & A = \mu \left( {\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {B_i } } \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \mu _k \left( {\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {B_i } } \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {\mu _k \left( {B_i } \right)} } \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \left( {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\mu _k \left( {B_i } \right)} } \right)  \cr 
  & B = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty  {\mu \left( {B_i } \right)}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\mu \left( {B_i } \right)} } \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left( {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \mu _k \left( {B_i } \right)} \right)} } \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } \left( {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{k \to \infty } \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\mu _k \left( {B_i } \right)} } \right) \cr} 
$$

So I have to prove that I can invert the order of that limits. I'm not using the fact that the sequence is increasing, and I'm not sure how to use it, I don't how practically nothing about double sequences.

If I consider the double sequence $
a_{kn}  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\mu _k \left( {B_i } \right)} 
$

At least this sequence has two nice properties:

$i)$ $
a_{kn}  \leqslant a_{(k + 1)n} 
$

$ii)$ $
a_{kn}  \leqslant a_{k(n + 1)} 
$

I'm not sure if that guarantees that $A=B$ please help me )=!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $b_n$ is a non-decreasing sequence, then $\lim_n b_n = \sup_n b_n$.

For any sequence, $\sup_n \sup_m a_{m,n} = \sup_m \sup_n a_{m,n} = \sup_{m,n} a_{m,n}$.

If $(m,n) \leq (m',n')$, then you have $a_{m,n} \leq a_{m',n'}$. Then taking the $\sup$ of the right first, then the left, it follows that if $m\leq m'$, then $\sup_n a_{m,n} \leq \sup_n a_{m',n}$, and similarly for $\sup_m a_{m,n}$.

Hence, loosely speaking, if the sequence is non-decreasing, you can replace the $\sup$ by a $\lim$.

It follows that $\lim_m \lim_n a_{m,n} =\lim_n \lim_m a_{m,n}$.